# Subir o max-width: das imagens para 640px

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, layout

### Subir o max-width: das imagens para 640px

Aqui é 630px apenas. No SOzão o max-width é 640px.

São dois sites separados, mas manter a consistência dos dois ajuda a "reciclar" imagens na tradução dos posts, ou mesmo criar novas para fazer cross-posting. As de 640px cabem perfeitamente no SOpt sem mexer no resto da página, não vejo motivo para as nossas terem esta "economia" de 10px.

(Descobri isso justamente por ver que uma imagem no SOzão estava ok, e aqui a mesma distorceu um pouco, em certa ocasião)

*A pedido do @Bacco*

[image: teste]

Imagem de teste com 640px   ^